# Need help setting up Samba 4.11.6 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

I'm trying to get Samba running on my Ubuntu home server. The installation seems to have gone smoothly, but I can't get past some of the first steps.

Here's the OS and Samba versions I'm running:

> ```
> OS:            Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x86_64 
> Kernel:        5.4.0-29-generic 
> Samba version: Version 4.11.6-Ubuntu
> ```

Here's the output from `sudo smbd -i`:

> ```
> smbd version 4.11.6-Ubuntu started.
> Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2019
> INFO: Profiling support unavailable in this build.
> **No builtin nor plugin backend for tdbsam​ found**
> ```

Here's the output from `smbpasswd -a my_user`:

> ```
> **No builtin nor plugin backend for tdbsam​ found**
> **Failed to open passdb!**
> ```

I can't configure or test anything until I can add users, etc. ***This is where I need help.*** I've spent hours trying to find an answer, but nothing has helped so far. I've experimented with the smb.conf to see if that has an impact.

I'm sure someone will ask, so here's the output from `sudo testparm`:

> ```
> Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
> Loaded services file OK.
> Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
>
> Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions
>
> # Global parameters
> [global]
>     log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
>     logging = file
>     map to guest = Bad User
>     max log size = 1000
>     obey pam restrictions = Yes
>     pam password change = Yes
>     panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
>     passdb backend = tdbsam​:/var/lib/samba/private/passdb.tdb
>     passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
>     passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
>     server min protocol = SMB2
>     server role = standalone server
>     server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
>     unix password sync = Yes
>     workgroup = MY_WORKGROUP
>     fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
>     fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
>     fruit:zero_file_id = yes
>     fruit:posix_rename = yes
>     fruit:veto_appledouble = no
>     fruit:model = MacSamba
>     fruit:metadata = stream
>     fruit:advertise_fullsync = true​
>     fruit:time machine = yes​
>     fruit:aapl = yes​
>     idmap config * : backend = tdb
>     vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
>
> [TimeMachine]
>     comment = Time Machine Backup Disk​
>     create mask = 0600
>     directory mask = 0700
>     path = /var/timemachine
>     posix locking = No
>     fruit:time machine = yes
> ```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by completely uninstalling Samba, then reinstalling.

I'm not sure what was missed or failed during the first install. Oh well.